# How to remove sidebar modules on Magento 1.9 Home page

Tags: magento

I have tried anything possible but no lack.
My home page is set to 1 column but the sidebar are still there.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that your Home Page assigned `1 Column` Layout and Layout Update XML textarea is empty.

Also Please check in `1 Column` Phtml file that there is no condition applied for home page to include sidebar

Answer (score 0):

To make the Home Page set to 1 Column layout do the below steps:

> 1. Navigate to CMS > Pages > Manage Content
> 2. Select Home Page > Design Tab > Layout > 1column
> 3. Clear complete cache

```
If you check "packagae/theme/layout/page.xml", the template is set to "3columns.phtml"
```

Make sure this is not being called and the backend 1column layout update is called.

Hope this helps. Happy to Help!

Happy Coding...

Comment: Hi Shivani, thanks for the quick reply. I have edited the page.hlm template at this path: /httpdocs/app/design/frontend/ma_dilima/ma_dilima3 from 

<block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">

to

<block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/1column.phtml"> 

The front end is calling the 1column.phtml

 The problem still persist.

Comment: What all do you see in the SIDEBAR? can you share a screenshot?

Comment: how do I post a screenshot?

Comment: Do you see CART , promotional messages on the sidebar?

Comment: Yes, I do and I don't want them.

Comment: Can you put on your template path hints and be sure that the template that is being called is 1column.phtml? Check the 1column.phtml if no custom coding has been done. And clear /var/ folders.